# Podcast #64 - Discussion Ideas. (Unofficial)

Tags: discussion, podcast

What would you like to see discussed on Podcast #64?

Please post only one topic per user and look down the list and vote up things you'd like to see. You can be as detailed as you wish.

[Podcast #65 thread is here.](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/12785/podcast-65-discussion-ideas-unofficial)

---

[podcast #64](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2009/08/podcast-64/)   [transcript wiki](https://stackoverflow.fogbugz.com/default.asp?W29074)

Answer (score 17):

Lessons learned in a year:

- Has anything happened "exactly as expected"?
- Do users behave better/worse/weirder than expected?
- Any technical lessons learned?
- What would you have done differently if you'd started again?
- What do you expect for the next year?

EDIT: As per Kyle's suggestion, I've recorded this and sent it in. We'll see whether it gets in the 'cast :)

Comment: +1 for "what would you do differently." I always wondered.

Comment: oooh Podcast #64: Postmortem...sounds tasty.

Comment: You should definitely record this and send it in as a listener question.

Comment: Kyle: that's a great idea - will do.

Comment: Wow...a year already?

Comment: I seriously think they should have Jon Skeet on the show.

Answer (score 7):

I would like for them to discuss the possibility of partnering up with http://thedailywtf.com/. You have to admit, between SO, Meta, SF, and SU...there is no shortage of content which could be used for an entire series of TDWTF articles.

Comment: Oooh! And there could be a "Belongs on TDWTF" close option!

Comment: Shog9: I actually suggested the exact same thing to Pesto in IRC less than an hour ago.

Comment: I would be so happy if I could close questions (or, more appropriately, answers) and have them automatically submitted to Alex to include on the front page of TDWTF.

Comment: @TheTXI: you guys wake up too damn early.

Comment: Shog9: You're just a lazy waste of a developer.

Comment: I'm a lazy waste of *many* things, TheTXI. Don't sell me short!

Comment: I have to sell you short because you don't fetch a good price on the open market.

Comment: I have yet to find a decent store that will exchange goods or services for reputation.

Comment: Need RepOverflow.com...

Comment: Did anyone follow TheTXI's link?

Comment: Be careful with links.  That URL points to a spam site.  Maybe you meant http://thedailywtf.com

Comment: I corrected the link. =)

Comment: Especially as Alex of dailyWTF sells their ad space.

Answer (score 5):

Since it'll be close to the anniversary mark, I say try and get some of the top users together for a pow wow to discuss the dynamic of how they do SO. They're at the top for a reason, and have a lot of respect with the SO community, so hearing from them would be valuable.

Comment: We don't respect them. We just keep up a respectful facade because we live in fear of being smited by the vengeful gods that they are.

Comment: I'd like to see that Welbog guy on a podcast. I think he's a pretty cool guy. eh hates repuattion and doesnt afraid of anything.

Comment: @The TXI We need a +1L for LOLs on comments.

Answer (score 0):

They should start a timer and spend like 5 solid minutes on every show specifically not talking about a programming topic.  These guys love and live programming so much, I bet that would be difficult for them to pull off and possibly funny to listen to.

Some ideas:

- Films or DVDs or TV shows recently watched
- Sporting events
- personal stuff, family life
- etc.

Comment: They've talked about playing video games on a podcast a while back, and I remember it was the funniest bit i had heard in a while.