# Podcast #65 - Discussion Ideas. (Unofficial)

Tags: discussion, podcast

What would you like to see discussed on Podcast #65?

Please post only one topic per user and look down the list and vote up things you'd like to see. You can be as detailed as you wish.

[Podcast #64 thread is here.](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/11030/podcast-64-discussion-ideas-unofficial)

[Podcast #66 thread is here.](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/14303/podcast-66-discussion-ideas-unofficial)

---

[Podcast #65](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2009/08/podcast-65/) [transcript wiki](https://stackoverflow.fogbugz.com/default.asp?W29076)

Comment: I'm holding out for the Welbog and Rich B interviews.

Comment: Wel-Who? Rich B is a good idea so...

Comment: You wound me, sir.

Answer (score 5):

[Lesson learned](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/11030/podcast-64-discussion-ideas-unofficial/11040#11040)

If you make a new thread, I have to link to the old answers ;)

Comment: Aye it's a good answer from Jon

Answer (score 2):

Superuser.com - is it valid to discuss issues on computer-like devices, such as iPhone, BlackBerry, etc?

Answer (score 0):

I'd like to hear a bit about how Jeff transitioned into the StackOverflow world.  e.g. what "gig" did he have before this?  I know he ran/runs Coding Horror but was there more?

I think many of us have side projects that we're hoping to get off the ground but we often struggle with being able to dedicate enough time to them whilst still maintaining full-time employment elsewhere.

Thus, any tips, tricks to "working for the man" while moving towards "working for yourself".

Comment: Read the older issues of Coding Horror and his About page, it's all there. I think he quit his previous job and started Stack Overflow.

Comment: thanks for Coding Horror about page note. I wasn't expecting that much detail to be there but I was pleasantly surprised.